# ubuntu server 20.04 keeps giving [FAILED]failed /cdrom

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04

I keep trying to install ubuntu server 20.04 but after the drive partitioning step I get [FAILED]failed /cdrom

Comment: i also get a failed unmounting cdrom

Answer (score 1):

After this error, it should also tell you to take out the install media and press enter. It will then reboot, then say Invalid Partition Table, press enter on this screen a couple of times, then it should continue with the installation. It will ask for username and password. Then it will give you your command line :)

Comment: i completely forgot i asked this and just switched to centOS which has now gone stream smh